# can you get year/month/date from Date().getTime

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to store date in DB is. Using

```
new Date().getTime()
```

seems to be the most common but is it possible to get the year/month/date from the timestamp? or is getTime meant as a way to sort data. Should I just store new Date() directly if I want retrieve the y/m/d information again?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Where are you storing it? In a database, in a cookie, in a variable on the page...

Comment: var day = new Date(y, m, d).getTime()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getTime()` is useful for saving in files and databases because it represents the date and time as a single number, which is very compact. It's also represented in UTC, so the timezone doesn't matter.

You can convert it back to a `Date` with:

```
var thatTime = Date(retrievedTime);
```

Then you can use `thatTime.getYear()`, `thatTime.getMonth()`, etc. to extract parts of the saved time.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateObject = new Date();
var year = dateObject.getYear();
var month = dateObject.getMonth();
var date = dateObject.getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar is absolutely correct. However, if you want the year, month and date information stored in an easily readable way, you can go two ways (assuming you only want the date and not the time):

1. Use the `Date` object's `getYear`, `getMonth` and `getDate` methods respectively and store them in separate fields (less processing for display and you can choose which parts you want, but more parsing required for sorting, etc.)
2. [`toDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) (and [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) for non-American-English and flexibility) gives a human-readable string like "Wed Jul 28 1993" (and then you'd slice off the first 4 characters).

Comment: thanks, but I think having one field saving the timestamp is more efficient, although it means you may need to convert back to a date object after retrieving using Date(timestamp) then applying getYear,getMonth,getDate to get the appropriate information

Comment: @Saad: Absolutely. This is better for processing time but worse for space; just a suggestion for some common use-cases.